# Android - SQLiteException while deleting record

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Currently We have one application in which we are receiving many crash reports while deleting record from database .

Here is method in which app is crashing.

```
public int deleteGroupMap(String nickName) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        return database.delete(TABLE_NAME_GROUP_MAP, COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME + " = '" + nickName + "'", null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        database.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but we am getting following exception:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "adz": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM groups_map WHERE
>   gmap_nick_name = ''adz.'

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Probably, `adz` is passed as `"adz"`. Try replacing the eventual `"`s with `\"`.

Comment: i thiunk you havae to change .....COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME + " = '"....... to ........ COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME + " = "........  in that uby mistake you make '" where it required "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [delete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) signature:

```
int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

Third argument is where args:

> You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced by the
>   values from whereArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

It's automatically escaped, so there is no need to put quotes (', ") manually.

Use where args instead of strings concating:

```
database.delete(TABLE_NAME_GROUP_MAP, COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME + " = ?", new String[] { nickName });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
public int deleteGroupMap(String nickName) {
SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
try {
   database .execSQL("DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME_GROUP_MAP + " WHERE " + COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME  + " = "+nickName+"");
   database .close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    database.close();
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return database.delete(TABLE_NAME_GROUP_MAP, COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME + "= ?" , new String[]{Long.toString(nickName)});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also use parameter markers because appending values directly is error prone when the source contains special characters.

try following because it will also prevent SQL injections to your app

database.delete(TABLE_NAME_GROUP_MAP, COLUMN_GMAP_NICK_NAME + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(nickName));